# Front cover grids for Android smartphones for blind people to use a screen divided in physical areas

Tags: smartphones, android, tablet, printer, touchscreen

When I used to go to school there used to be rectangular plastic sheets with shapes inside, such as circles, ovals, squares, and rectangles, that you could trace with a pen or with a pencil.

I was wondering whether there are any plastic sheet covers for blind people that can be printed and stuck onto the computer screen of an Android device, that actually had ridges, so that the blind person could make sense of the screen having areas in a more intuitive way than just dragging and clicking their fingers around something that is just flat and smooth, and appears, as a single, one-piece, surface.

For instance, apps could be coded for phones that could take such covers, and the cover design profiles downloaded from the app's download place and printed with a computer plastic printer (or bought from the plastic printer cover store, or any online store that was blind user friendly and offered them, perhaps even though an app), and then the blind user could hook it up, open the app through Google Assistant, and user it with the onscreen touch feedback provided as per grid surrounded context, in the app.

Thank you for supporting my idea.

Has anyone done anything similar?

Where can I get this stuff from?

Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea but I don't think this is a mass produced product. You have kind of answered your own question: It will need to be 3D printed yourself or by a shop that does 3D printing to-order and the apps have to be custom designed to use these covers.

Comment: Even simpler than 3D printing would be to use ordinary stencil material of sufficient durability. The necessary tactile references could be laser cut or die cut (or hand cut!) in the appropriate locations and also cut i a manner to identify the specific app to be used with that stencil/overlay.

Comment: Just wondering if you have asked any blind people if they would like this idea ?